# add serach bar into nav bar for iphone

Tags: iphone

i have leftnavbutton and rightnav button  now how to add search bar in between them

right now i am using this 
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

but this bar goes up when you serach item downside  so i want to make it at top always visible;

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by add searchbar below the navigationbar and below that add tableview, so when you scroll the table searchbar will not move.

You can also add searchbar in navigationvar using the following code

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchbar;
```

Comment: Hi reena 

if i do that self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar;
then my searchbar is shrinking on top

lets say is it possible to keep my serach bar below nav bar but fixed should not move when i go down the table

Comment: first you just put searchbar in your view and below that put uitableview then it will nor move when you go down to the table

Comment: i did exactly what you said but of no use

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; 
wil always push serach bar on top of table view

Comment: ya now need for tableHederview.

Comment: if i reove that then  only table view is showing not search bar

Comment: as i have told you previously "first put searchbar in your view and below that put uitableview then it will not move when you go down to the table " searchbar and tableview will be the separate control 

Remove searchbar from tableHeaderview

Comment: put searchbar at the top (x = 0, y = 0)
and for tableview (x = 0,y = 45)

Comment: NO NO NO NO NOOOOOOOOO i did 4 times what you said ... plz tell me is there any other way

Comment: i dont want to die i want to live as life is beautiful :(

Comment: do you know how to set frame of any control?

Comment: whenevr you put tableview.it will take over all screen
how setframe will help here  can you show  me

Comment: //Add the search bar
 
 self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"w2eat_3.png"]];//Travelscroll.png
   
 
#pragma mark serach bar
 
 //self.navigationItem.titleView=searchBar;
  self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
 searchBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
 searchBar.showsCancelButton=YES;

Comment: open your .XIB file. select your table 
go to Tools menuitem -> size inspector
you can see size & position in view size tag, you can set there your frame.

or you can also change the size by mouse dragging as you do in other controls

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO i am using tableview (drag n drop to my rootviewcont   then inside table view i put serachbar   this bar is on top and table view is aleready der,,, though i made another view with new search bar and table view with all those gap its  not working            HEY BHAGWAN UTHA LE

Comment: that means controller which contains the table is UiTableViewControler.
not UiViewControler. You need to specify this.

You can't add any control in UiTableViewControler. To do that you have to take UiVIewController.

Comment: sari ramayan pad li aor aap puch rahi ho sita kon thi ... sahi ha :-)